# how to produce data from nodejs app to firehose

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, stream, amazon-kinesis

We have configured a firehose data delivery stream which should used as buffer of different types of event generated by Nodejs app.

Apparently it looks like the app can't stream the data to the firehose stream, with the following error message:

> couldn't stream ResourceNotFoundException: Stream my-stream under account  not found.

The way I generate the data and use the kinesis obj is as follows:

```
function streamKinesis(req, res){
    var params = {
        Records: [],
        StreamName: "stream_name"
    };

    params.Records.push({
        Data: JSON.stringify(req.body),
        PartitionKey: 'bla'
    });

    var kinesis = new AWS.Kinesis({ region: 'eu-west-1' });
    kinesis.listStreams(function (err, data) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        }
    });
    kinesis.putRecords(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("couldn't stream", err.stack);
        }
        else {
            console.log("INFO - successfully send stream");
            res.send({success: true});
        }
    });
}
```

I'd appreciate any feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case was the class used, which in this case was kinesis, instead of firehouse. 
Below attached the code of how it should be written in case someone else faces a situation where the app need to produce data on the firehouse streaming.
In AWS documentation all it redirects you is to the kinesis api documentation.

The code snippest:

```
function streamKinesis(req, res){
var params = {
    Record: {Data: JSON.stringify(req.body)},
    DeliveryStreamName: "[stream_name]"
};
var firehouse = new AWS.Firehose();
firehouse.putRecord(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("couldn't stream", err.stack);
    }
    else {
        console.log("INFO - successfully send stream");
        res.send({success: true});
    }
});
}
```